# Gemfile syntax error after Bootstrap-sass install

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, heroku, rubygems, syntax-error, gemfile

After numerous "git push heroku master" rejections due to "no Cedar-support app detected" I found I should run bundle install.

```
$bundle install

    Gemfile syntax error:
      <<<<<<< HEAD
        ^
    /Users/Wes/Sites/code/omrails/Gemfile:21: syntax error, unexpected ===, expecting
    keyword_end
    =======
       ^
```

Alright, checking Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'jquery-rails'

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'

  <<<<<<< HEAD
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~>2.3.1.2'
=======
>>>>>>> edeb28700d0603990afb9005dd7d084890def28f
end
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am new to the community.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
```

And

```
=======
>>>>>>> edeb28700d0603990afb9005dd7d084890def28f
```

These lines are results of merge between branches in your git repository, where conflicts appeared.
You should take a look at [Git How To: Resolving Conflicts](http://githowto.com/resolving_conflicts).

Remove those three lines and your bundle install should run properly.